# Partitioned positive definite matrix property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices, schur-complement

I am interested in the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a real symmetric positive definite matrix partitioned into four submatrices as follows:
> $$
> X = \begin{pmatrix} 
>      A&B\\
>      B^T & C
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> Define the symmetric matrix $Y$ by:
> $$
> Y = C - B^TA^{-1}B
> $$
> Is $Y$ always positive definite?

I suspect that the answer is yes. I have attempted using the definition of positive definite matrices to prove this and also tried looking for counterexamples, but have so far been unsuccessful. I would greatly appreciate any help or recommendations.

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia page on the Schur complement. You are welcome to post an  answer to your own question.

Comment: Alternatively, consider $x^TAx$ where $x=\pmatrix{-A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}v\\ v}$.

Comment: Take a look at Jean Gallier's [notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Recognizing that $Y$ is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $A$ in $X$, we can use the following condition for positive definiteness of a Schur complement:

> Let $X$ be a symmetric matrix of real numbers given by
> $$
> X=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B^T&C\end{pmatrix}
> $$
> Then if A is invertible, then X is positive definite if and only if A and its complement X/A are both positive definite:
> $$
> {\displaystyle X\succ 0\Leftrightarrow A\succ 0,X/A=C-B^{\mathsf {T}}A^{-1}B\succ 0}
> $$

Since $X$ is positive definite, $A$ is positive definite and is therefore invertible. Then by the above equivalence statement, we know that $Y=C-B^TA^{-1}B$ is positive definite.